# How to add this js on localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you help me on this ... I have this code, and I wanna add it on localStorage any solution

```
const sun = 'sun';
const moon = 'moon';
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('#darkmodeToggle');

function switchTheme(e) {
  if (document.documentElement.getAttribute('data-theme') == 'light') {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    this.innerHTML = sun;
  }
  else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
    this.innerHTML = moon;
  }    
}
toggleSwitch.addEventListener('click', switchTheme, false);

if(window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches) {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
  toggleSwitch.innerHTML = moon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save the user's dark mode selection, so you can just save a single value in `localStorage`, so you can use

```
localStorage.setItem("darkmood", "on");
```

Then You can use

```
localStorage.getItem("darkmood");
```

To get user selection